# django issue with url receive from API

Tags: python, django, api, url

Below is a redirect link from API
I would like to render my urls.py

> http://127.0.0.0:8000/test-pay-redirect?token=60257a578aedc20bd1a6892c&mode=popup&tap_id=chg_TS014820212148r1N41102850

re_path(r"^test-pay-redirect/",views.paytestredirect,name='test_pay_redirect'),

path("test-pay-redirect/",views.paytestredirect,name='test_pay_redirect'),
i try both
but it couldnt connect with this urls

Comment: both commands look good. The problem might be somewhere else!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a simple demo project for you. https://github.com/michaelhaar/Answer-for-Stackoverflow-66160632

Run the `python manage.py runserver` command and visit http://localhost:8000/test-pay-redirect/?token=60257a578aedc20bd1a6892c&mode=popup&tap_id=chg_TS014820212148r1N41102850

You should see something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the trailing slash in your url route!?

```
path("test-pay-redirect", views.paytestredirect, name='test_pay_redirect')
```